# Composite function injectivity

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

I have a function $f : R → R$ such that $(f \circ f \circ f)(x) = (f \circ f)(x) + x \hspace{4mm} \forall x \in R$

how would i go about proving its injectivity? I have tried finding $f(x)$ but to no avail, would this be possible? Would it also be possible given this function, to compute something out of $f(x)$? Something such as $f(0)$?

Comment: Thanks for using LaTeX formatting, but it isn't too clear what's going on around the 'forall' symbol.

Comment: sorry, i will try to edit the equation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By contradiction *(not necessary, but this makes the argument a tiny bit cleaner, in my opinion)*. Suppose there exist reals $x\neq y$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$.

This implies $(f\circ f)(x)=(f\circ f)(y)$ and $(f\circ f\circ f)(x)=(f\circ f\circ f)(y)$, the latter from which by definition
$$
(f\circ f)(x) + x = (f\circ f)(y) +y
$$
and using the fact that $(f\circ f)(x)=(f\circ f)(y)$, this implies in turn
$$
x=y,
$$
contradiction.

---

Let us write $y\stackrel{\rm def}{=} f(0)$. From our equation, we know that $$f^{(2)}(y) = f^{(3)}(0)= f^{(2)}(0)+0 = f^{(2)}(0) = f(y)$$
which implies, applying $f$ to both sides,
$
f^{(3)}(y) = f^{(2)}(y)
$
so that, using again our initial relation which states that $f^{(3)}(y)=f^{(2)}(y)+y$, we get
$$
f^{(2)}(y) = f^{(2)}(y)+y
$$
and we conclude that $y=0$.

Comment: thanks for your answer, would it be possible to compute something out of $f(x)$ using this? for instance, how would i go about computing $f(0)$? (see edit)

Comment: @ChrisGeorgiou Yes, see my edit.